interpretion of direct OSEK NetworkManagement How ECU should react when interrupt LimpHome mode (TError, Tmax, Twbs)
I am a tester, working in one OEM project which require (direct) OSEK NM. we bought OSEK stack and also NetworkTestSuite but it report failed in some cases; interrupt LimpHome.
We found some conflict in the requirement (Fig.1 vs Fig.2) and already tried to ask ISO17356 Committee. unfortunately, their feedback are the OSEK expert are retired and suggest to ask developer. therefore, would like to ask questions below:
here is the Scenario
(1) our ECU1 got no communication in network (ECU2, ECU3, etc.), once NMtxcount=5 it will switch to LimpHome mode (start TError=1000ms), during this time (before TError lapse) ECU1 receive 2 NM messages (ECU2, ECU3).
Time    ID          Name    Data        Comment
179.445 18FF0001    ECU1    FE 01 04
179.545 18FF0001    ECU1    FD 01 04    NMtxcount 1
179.805 18FF0001    ECU1    FE 01 04
179.905 18FF0001    ECU1    FD 01 04    NMtxcount 2
180.165 18FF0001    ECU1    FE 01 04
180.265 18FF0001    ECU1    FD 01 04    NMtxcount 3
180.525 18FF0001    ECU1    FE 01 04
180.625 18FF0001    ECU1    FD 01 04    NMtxcount 4
180.885 18FF0001    ECU1    FE 01 04    
181.017 18FF0002    ECU2    FE 02 04    Diff 132ms
181.028 18FF0003    ECU3    FE 03 04    Diff 11ms

****Question 1: shall ECU1 interrupt TError, goto NMIniReset, therefore send Alive message?
or shall ECU1 go InitLimpHome, start and wait TError lapse, send LimpHome message once (dont care received messages as interrupt, dont attempt to communicate into Ring as fast as possible), and then goto NMIniReset which send Alive message?
when we look at the LimpHome description (ISO17356-5 2.2.4.4 page19): repetitively send until it is able to transmit its own ring message to the bus and until it is able to receive NM message of other nodes correctly. and several facts from other diagram; point out LimpHome→NMReset when receive message.
therefore, I interpret that when receive/able to send message on bus, it shall process as fast as possible to form a Ring/recover communication, in other word leave LimpHome because no error in communication.
our customer argument: ECU1 require to inform other ECU that it will change configuration to NormalNM/or leave LimpHome, therefore send LimpHome with Sleep.Ind reset.
which in the end give a delay of 1s from TError. to initiate new Ring.


****Question 2: in Fig.1 vs Fig.2 there is conflict in LimpHomeActive that SDL diagram dont wait for TError lapse and send LimpHome message, but go directly NMIniReset and send Alive message.
on the other hand, Fig.1 LimpHomeNMActive wait to send LimpHome message before allow to go NMReset.
What do you think, What is your implementation/experience?
****Question 3: there is also a scenario (2) that ECU1 already in and send LimpHome message and about togo Sleep when Twbs lapse, it receive NM messages from ECU2 & ECU3 before Twbs lapse.
ID          Name    Data        Comment
18FF0001    ECU1    FC 01 04
18FF0001    ECU1    FC 01 04    
18FF0001    ECU1    FC 01 84    LimpHome Sleep.Ind set
18FF0002    ECU2    FE 02 04    
18FF0003    ECU3    FE 03 04

    

I interpret it the similar case as above; goto NMInitReset and send Alive as first message (regarding to SDL diagram).
however, our customer feedback is to go InitLimpHome, start and wait TError lapse, send LimpHome message with reset Sleep.Indication bit with successor id (ECU2/3) in addition.
What do you think, What is your implementation/experience?
Action done:

tried to clarify with ISO 17356 Committee. suggestion to consult Developer, check AUTOSAR, no more expert comment (they are retired already).
looked at AUTOSAR specification. not mention of OSEK NM specification. only provide support interface that allow third party to offer support.
tried to reach supplier expert who invole directly in OSEK project. could not be found.
asked customer for a requirement/specification. no success. only refer to the (conflict) diagram (Fig.1)
consult OSEK-VDX.org. in Progress.

Expectation:

as a Standard, it shall be handle globally/equally/unambiguously. shall not be interpret differently.
brainstroming/get comment from the community, how the interpretion we have in common/other opinion.
get support information/reference/experience in implementation.

